# How do I answer this question?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $u=f(r)$,where $r=\|x\|$ and f is differentiable .

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\Big)^2=|f'(r)|^2$ .
what I've done so far is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial x_i} 
&= f'(r) \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} 
 = f'(r) \cdot \frac{\partial \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}}{\partial x_i}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$2r\partial_i r =\partial_i  (r^2) =\partial_i ( x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)=2x_i  $$
that is $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial_{x_i} } =\frac{x_i}{r }$$
and 
$$\sum_i \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial_{x_i} }\right)^2   = \sum_i \left(\frac{x_i}{r }\right)^2  =\frac{1}{r^2 } \sum_i x_i^2  = 1$$

Comment: I get it know. ty